# Using a object across multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have been attempting to have a object that I can use across multiple view controllers by following this thread.

[One instance across multiple views in Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851158/one-instance-across-multiple-views)

But it has not been working for me.  So I started with the basics to see what was going on.  I created a local instance of the object.

```
PlayerData *playerOne   = [[PlayerData alloc] init];
playerOne.completedRound += 1;
```

I can inspect this in the debugger and I see 0 for all values when I create it and then it gets updated by the appropriate line of code so I feel like my object class is written correctly.

When I try to define the object in my header file to like this:

In my UIViewController.h I added the following

```
#import "PlayerData.h"

PlayerData *playerOne;

@property (nonatomic, retain) PlayerData *playerOne;
```

In my UIViewContoller.m I have added the following

```
#import "PlayerData.h"

@synthesize playerOne;

playerOne.completedRound += 1;
```

I cannot get it to work.  The code compiles fine but viewing the instance in the debugger non of the variable ever get set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possibly silly questions:

1. Does `[PlayerData init]` initialise your property to zero?
2. Does your `UIViewController` `alloc`/`init` the `PlayerData` object before you try to increment it?

Comment: That was it.  I thought since the values were not even 0 that might be a problem but I was think the @synthesize should have done that.